# How can I access programmatically created UI Elements in Xamarin.Forms : timepicker

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uielement

I got a method which is creating UI Element programmatically. Example:

```
Label label1 = new Label(); 
label1.Text = "Testlabel";

TimePicker timepicker1 = new TimePicker();
timepicker1.Time = new TimeSpan(07, 00, 00);
```

After that I add both of them in an already existing StackLayout.

```
stacklayout1.Children.Add(label1);
stacklayout1.Children.Add(timepicker1);
```

A user of my app can create this multiple times.
Now my question is, how can I access, for example, the second/ better all of TimePickers which were created?

Comment: `stackLayout1.Children[x]` or use the named reference `timepicker1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

Use **ID**:

```
var id = label1.Id;
var text = (stacklayout1.Children.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault() as myLabel).Text;
```

Use **index**:

```
Label labelOne = stacklayout1.Children[0] as Label;
```

Use **tag**:

Create a custom property `tag` to the label:

```
public class myLabel : Label{ 

    public int tag { get; set; }
}
```

And find label by the tag:

```
var labels = stacklayout1.Children.Where(x => x is myLabel).ToList();

foreach (myLabel childLabel in labels)
{
  if (childLabel.tag == 0)
  {

  }
}
```

BTW, if you create the label in **xaml**, you can use `findbyname`:

```
Label label = stacklayout1.FindByName("labelA") as Label;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timepickers = stacklayout1.Children.Where(child => child is TimePicker);
```

Will return an IEnumerable of all of the timepickers added to your StackLayout. You will have to also add using System.Linq to your usings at the top of the page.